# Remote reboot for a fedora 27 machine with luks encryption

Tags: ssh, fedora, remote, luks, reboot

I run Fedora 27 on a pc, that mainly runs scripts for my work. In the beginning I was using it as my workstation so I chose full disk encryption while installing. But now the encryption serves no use anymore. I plan to make a clean reinstall with no encryption at some point.

However I have to leave for some days and I want to have ssh access to that pc, and be able to remotely reboot it. Not something fancy. I just want to reboot it and leave it waiting at the Gnome user login screen. What is the easiest way to do this? I do not mind the security. I just want an easy way to bypass the boot passphrase remotely.

I saw some tutorials about Dropbear SSH, but I don't have the time to experiment with this solution at this point. Is there a fast and minimally meddling way to achieve this? Even some file where I can write the actual passphrase and let it read it from there?

Answer (score 1):

[dracut-crypt-ssh](https://github.com/dracut-crypt-ssh/dracut-crypt-ssh) is a dracut module which starts a dropbear ssh server during the initramfs, so you can ssh in to provide the passphrase and decrypt the root filesystem. I use this on a number of servers scattered all over the planet, for which I don't have console access, and it works quite well.

Comment: I have seen this, but i really couldn't understand the documentation and as I said, I don't have time to experiment, or format and reinstall in case something breaks. For example, in the documentation it says:

"For a static network configuration, use something along the lines of

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="... rd.neednet=1 ip=192.168.0.100::192.168.0.1:255.255.255.0:centos:enp0s8:off"

which i do not understand

Comment: @odorf You have to bring up networking in the initramfs. So you would just have to substitute your own network configuration. It's very simple.